# QLabel not resizing after changing its text

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem, qlabel

I have a QLabel centered in a custom QGraphicsPolygonItem and I'm using a QAction to change the labels text, but when the text changes the label size doesn't change, I want it to resize to the size of the new text and keep it centered. Here's my custom item constrctor:

```
DiagramItem::DiagramItem(DiagramType diagramType, QMenu *contextMenu,
         QGraphicsItem *parent)
: QGraphicsPolygonItem(parent){
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pMyProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setText(QString("I AM A SQARE DADADA"));
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : blue; }");
pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
pMyProxy->setPos(this->boundingRect().center()-label->rect().center());
...
```

Here's the slot I'm using to change the text of the label:

```
void MainWindow::setItemLabel(){
if(!scene->selectedItems().isEmpty())
{
    auto *item = scene->selectedItems().first();
    if(!(item->childItems().isEmpty()))
    {
        auto proxy = static_cast<QGraphicsProxyWidget *>(item->childItems().first());
        if(proxy)
        {
            auto label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(proxy->widget());
            if(label)
            {
                QDialog *diag = new QDialog(this);
                QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();
                QLineEdit *lt = new QLineEdit();
                QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok
                                                                    | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
                QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
                connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), diag, SLOT(accept()));
                connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), diag, SLOT(reject()));
                mainLayout->addWidget(lt);
                mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);

                diag->setLayout(mainLayout);
                if(diag->exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
                    QString *usrInpt = new QString();
                    *usrInpt = lt->text();
                    label->rect().setWidth(usrInpt->length());
                    label->setText(*usrInpt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting as a result, this is before triggering the slot above:
[image: BeforeSlotTriggere]
And here's what I'm getting after the slot is triggered:
[image: AfterSlotTriggered]

This line isn't doing anything too, and I have no idea why:

```
label->rect().setWidth(usrInpt->length());
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the size of the `QLabel` with `adjustSize()`, but even so the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` will not change its size causing the problem to persist, to correct we must overwrite `boundingRect()` and return the appropriate size, in addition to this the way you set the text does not is appropriate, if you are creating a class that has the label inside you could create a `setText()` method that updates the `QLabel` without the need to write a lot of code:

```
class GraphicsProxyWidget: public QGraphicsProxyWidget{
public:
    using QGraphicsProxyWidget::QGraphicsProxyWidget;
    QRectF boundingRect() const{
        if(widget())
            return QRectF(widget()->rect());
        return QGraphicsProxyWidget::boundingRect();
    }
};

class DiagramItem: public QGraphicsPolygonItem{
    QLabel *label;
    GraphicsProxyWidget *pMyProxy ;
public:
    explicit DiagramItem(DiagramType diagramType, QMenu *contextMenu, QGraphicsItem *parent=nullptr):QGraphicsPolygonItem(parent) {
        label = new QLabel;
        pMyProxy = new GraphicsProxyWidget(this);
        pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
        label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
        label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : blue; }");
        setText("I AM A SQARE DADADA");
        ...
    }
    void setText(const QString & text){
       label->setText(text);
       label->adjustSize();
       pMyProxy->setPos(boundingRect().center()-label->rect().center());
    }
};
```

and then the `setItemLabel` method would look like this:

```
void MainWindow::setItemLabel(){
    if(!scene->selectedItems().isEmpty())
    {
        auto *item = scene->selectedItems().first();
        DiagramItem *it = static_cast<DiagramItem *>(item);
        if(it){
            QDialog *diag = new QDialog(this);
            QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();
            QLineEdit *lt = new QLineEdit();
            QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok
                                                               | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
            QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
            connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), diag, SLOT(accept()));
            connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), diag, SLOT(reject()));
            mainLayout->addWidget(lt);
            mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);

            diag->setLayout(mainLayout);
            if(diag->exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
                it->setText(lt->text())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>

class GraphicsProxyWidget: public QGraphicsProxyWidget{
public:
    using QGraphicsProxyWidget::QGraphicsProxyWidget;
    QRectF boundingRect() const{
        if(widget())
            return QRectF(widget()->rect());
        return QGraphicsProxyWidget::boundingRect();
    }
};

class DiagramItem: public QGraphicsPolygonItem{
    QLabel *label;
    GraphicsProxyWidget *pMyProxy ;
public:
    explicit DiagramItem(QGraphicsItem *parent=nullptr):QGraphicsPolygonItem(parent) {
        label = new QLabel;
        pMyProxy = new GraphicsProxyWidget(this);
        pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
        label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
        label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : blue; }");
        setText(QString("I AM A SQARE DADADA"));
        setBrush(Qt::green);
    }
    void setText(const QString & text){
       label->setText(text);
       label->adjustSize();
       pMyProxy->setPos(boundingRect().center()-label->rect().center());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    w.setScene(scene);
    auto it = new DiagramItem;
    QPolygonF myPolygon({QPointF(-120, -80), QPointF(-70, 80),
                         QPointF(120, 80), QPointF(70, -80),
                         QPointF(-120, -80)});
    it->setPolygon(myPolygon);
    scene->addItem(it);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, [it](){
        it->setText("some text");
    });
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now the new text is centered, but the red background is still larger than the text, I thought `adjustSize()` would take care of it, why is that?

Comment: Yes, I did copy your code, all I did was separate function headers to .h and implementation to .cpp. I think maybe I'm not overriding `boundingRect()` correctly since I don't really know for sure where to put it, sorry for the newbie c++ struggle, but where should I place overridden functions from Qt headers?

Comment: @MatheusIanzer Never mess with working code until you confirm that it works. "All I did" is irrelevant - everyone says that. It's the software engineering equivalent of "hold my beer, watch this". Get it working as-is first, then commit to git, then change a small thing, verify that it still works, commit, and keep going like that, in small chunks. And yes, use git, even on little examples. Make it a habit. Then you'll embrace change instead of dreading it.